# How to calculate the standard deviation for a Gaussian Process?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, cholesky-decomposition, bayesian-optimization

I am quite new to Gaussian processes. A Gaussian Process looks like the following:

[image]

Where the dark blue line denotes the mean, and the filled-area denotes the mean+std and mean-std respectively.

From what I know, we can calculate the predicted mean function as follows

- $K$ denotes the kernel used
- $x_*$ denotes the x-coordinate to be
  predicted
- $x_d$ denotes all the 'training data'/previously sampled
  data):

$$ m( y_* | y_d) = \mu(x_*) + K(x_*, x_d) K(x_d, x_d)^{-1} (y_d - \mu (x_d)) $$

and the covariance function as follows:

$$ C(y_* | y_d) = K(x_*, x_*) - K(x_*, x_d) K(x_d, x_d)^{-1} K(x_d, x_*) $$

As I am currently new to Gaussian processes and try to understand the process before going into implementations, I started working through [this blog-post](http://katbailey.github.io/post/gaussian-processes-for-dummies/).
Here, the author calculates the following to end up with the standard-deviation:

```
K_ss = kernel(Xtest, Xtest)
K_s = kernel(Xtrain, Xtest, param)
K = kernel(Xtrain, Xtrain, param)

L = np.linalg.cholesky(K + 0.00005*np.eye(len(Xtrain)))
Lk = np.linalg.solve(L, K_s)

s2 = np.diag(K_ss) - np.sum(Lk**2, axis=0)
stdv = np.sqrt(s2)
```

My initial thought was that the covariance-function $C(y_* | y_d)$ can be used to calculate the standard deviation for each sampled data point in the above graph. However, looking at the code, I don't quite understand how this is done.

So my question is: How is the standard deviation calculated? And how can I then arrive at a graph like the above one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You've written the underlying closed-form equation and an implementation to produce the above plot. Is there a more specific part that you don't understand?

Comment: @KevinYang basically, why does the above code produce the above graph? Specifically, I don't understand what the code does / why it arrives at the same closed-form equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closed form equation for the predicted covariance inverts $K(x_d, x_d)$. However, using the Cholesky decomposition is faster and more numerically stable than directly taking the inverse. You can see the procedure laid out in Algorithm 2.1 of Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning. However, they don't show why they're equivalent, so I'll sketch it out here.

First

The closed-form equation gives a $n$ x $n$ covariance matrix for $d$ test points. The code only cares about it's diagonal. $K(x_*, x_*)$ is the $n$ a $n$ prior covariance between the test points, but the code extracts

```
np.diag(K_ss)
```

Note that

```
np.sum(Lk**2, axis=0)
```

is equivalent to:

```
np.diag(Lk.T @ Lk)
```

In other words,

```
Lk.T @ Lk
```

is somehow equivalent to

$$ K(x_*, x_d) K(x_d, x_d)^{-1} K(x_d, x_*) $$

The Cholesky decomposition of $K$ produces a lower triangular matrix $L$ with real positive diagonal entries such that

$$K = LL^T$$

Let $k_s = K(x_d, x_*)$ so that the least squares (np.linalg.solve) step outputs:
$$L_k = (L^TL)^{-1}L^Tk_s$$

$(AB)^T = B^TA^T$, $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, and $(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1} = A^{-T}$ , so

\begin{align}
L_k^TL_k &= k_s^T L [(L^TL)^{-1})]^T(L^TL)^{-1}L^Tk_s\\
L_k^TL_k &= k_s^T L (L^{-1}L^{-T})^TL^{-1}L^{-T}L^Tk_s\\
L_k^TL_k &= k_s^T L L^{-1}L^{-T}L^{-1}L^{-T}L^Tk_s\\
L_k^TL_k &= k_s^T L^{-T}L^{-1}k_s
\end{align}

From the definition of the Cholesky decomposition:
$$ K^{-1} = (LL^T)^{-1} = L^{-T}L^{-1}$$

Therefore:

$$ L_k^TL_k = k_s^T K^{-1} k_s $$

Finally, note that in the code, they add a small diagonal element to the training covariance so that:
$$K = K(x_d, x_d) + \sigma_n^2I$$.

The small diagonal element represents an estimate of the observation noise. That is, we assume that the observations $y$ are normally distributed with mean $f(x)$ and variance $\sigma_n^2$. Numerically, this helps to guarantee that the training covariance is positive definite.

Comment: I haven't talked about the actual plotting code, since you didn't post that part, but we can discuss that too if you're confused about that.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the awesome answer! :) Weirdly, I understood the plotting part. I had re-implemented everything using the usual matrix-inversion; I think I'll try the cholesky myself next. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @DaveTheAl You should implement the predictive mean using cholesky too :-)